# Ruby About $("#form > form").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))%>")

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Could any experts can explain why use $("#form > form") in edit.js, but not $("#form") ??

Here are some related code:**

Inside controller(app/controllers/entries_controller.rb)

```
def edit
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Inside app/views/entries/edit.js.erb template to set values into the form, here are the code:

```
$("#form > form").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form"))%>")
```

index page(app/views/entries/index.html.erb)

```
<h2>Entry form</h2>
<div id="form">
  <%= render :partial => "form" %>
</div>
```

form partial(app/views/entries/_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@entry, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :address, :rows => 3 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not require an expert. `$("#form > form")` means the `form` tag that is the child of a DOM with `id=form`.

Your form, which is generated by `<%= form_for(@entry, :remote => true) do |f| %>` is a child of `<div id="form">`

Answer (score 0):

The `#form` selector selects the element with the `id` of `form` - in this case, a `<div>` element.

The `#form > form` selector selects the form element that's an immediate child of the element with `id` of `form` - in this case, a `<form>` element directly inside the `<div id="form">` element.

You want to replace the form itself, not the `<div>` that contains it, so you want to select the form that's inside the `<div id="form">` element.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#form")` would match `<div>` with `id=form` that is on line 2 of `index.html.erb`

`$("#form > form")` matches `<form>` tag inside this `<div id=form>`. As you render your partial from inside `<div>`, `<form>` is actually where you search it.